# Taking a basis for the kernel and then extending it to $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I have the matrix $$D=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

I want to take a basis of $\ker D$ and then extend it to $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. So to do that I want to find the reduced row echelon form of $D$ and I calculate that as the identity matrix $$\text{RRE of D}=I=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Since adding $R_{3}$ to $R_{1}$ gives $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$ Then subtracting $R_{2}$ from $R_{3}$ yields $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ Then subtracting $3R_{3}$ from $R_{1}$ gives $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ Then subtracting $R_{3}$ from $R_{2}$ gives $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ Then adding $R_{2}$ to $R_{3}$ gives $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$ Finally multiplying $R_{3}$ by -1 gives $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Then a basis of the kernel of D would be $$s=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

And if I want to extend this basis to $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, then there is no work to be done since it already is one, if I'm not wrong?

Comment: You must have made a mistake.  $\textbf{rref}[D]\neq I_3$, and even if it were then that would imply something different about the kernel

Comment: Instead of doing row reduction, you can also observe that $D$ clearly has rank at least 2, but on the other hand the first and last columns are equal, so $(1\;0\;{-}1)$ is in the kernel. This means the kernel must have dimension 1, and is actually generated by $(1\;0\;{-}1)$.

Comment: @JMoravitz If you check the edit then you will see my calculations.

Comment: Row three plus row one gives $[1~3~1]$, not $[1~3~0]$.  Note, $0+1=1$, not $0+1=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the kernel of a matrix $A$ is the set of all vectors $x$ such that $Ax=0$.

Look at what happens for your supposed $s$ in this situation.  $D\cdot s = \begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\4\end{bmatrix}\neq 0$, so $s\not\in\ker(D)$.

Your row reduction is flawed in the first place.

$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&1&1\\1&2&1\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{(R_3-R_2-R_1)\mapsto R_3} \begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&1&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{R_1\leftrightarrow R_2}\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{R_1-R_2\mapsto R_1}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

If we were to interpret this the final step of solving a system of equations in for $Ax=0$, this says:

$\begin{cases}x_1+x_3=0\\x_2=0\\x_3~\text{is free}\end{cases}$

Letting $x_3=t$, this then says:

$\begin{cases} x_1=-t\\x_2=0\\x_3=t\end{cases}$ or rather $\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = t\cdot \begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Hence, $\ker(D)=span\left(\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)$

---

Looking at the case where something actually *does* row reduce to the identity, if $rref(A)=I_3$, that would imply that the final step in solving the system of equations $Ax=0$ is interpreted as:

$\begin{cases} x_1 = 0\\ x_2=0\\ x_3=0\end{cases}$, and so the kernel is trivial and is not spanned by anything.  (You could say it is the span of the zero vector, but the zero vector cannot be a part of any basis since it is linearly dependent even alone by itself).

---

If you wish to form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and you want one of the vectors in the basis to be the one found for the kernel, simply take *any other two* vectors such that they along with the basis for the kernel are all linearly independent from one another.  Common choices would be $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$.  These are both clearly linearly independent from one another and to the vector found earlier since the vector for the kernel has a nonzero third entry.

Something that will *not* work would be picking something like $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ since the two of these can be combined to make your third vector $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The kernel of $D$ is the subspace of vectors $x$ such that $Dx=0$, so:

$$Dx=0 \iff \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}0  \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} \iff
\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}t \\ 0 \\ -t\end{bmatrix}
$$
so the kernel of $D$ is the space spanned by 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}
$$

add any other two linearly independent vectors and you have a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.